# Retina UIImage being stretched incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I have two background assets for a `UINavigationBar`, one retina and one non-retina. The retina asset is appropriately named with `@2x.png` and the retina asset has a 1 pixel divider on the bottom. I'm using the following code to create the background `UIImage`.

```
UIImage *navigationBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_white_background"];
navigationBarImage = [navigationBarImage
                      resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0)];

[navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navigationBarImage
                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Oddly instead of being 1 pixel, the bottom divider is stretched to 2 pixels when it's actually displayed on the device and simulator. I can tell both visually and by capturing a screen shot and measuring the size.

My cap insets seem appropriate to me, any idea why the divider is being stretched?

Comment: Could you attach `navbar_white_background` image?

Comment: What is your iOS version?